# Are we too eager with tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, tag-synonyms

From the [suggested tag synonyms list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested), I see two that make me just a little bit curious:

`[typ] => [typo]`
`[never-friday-in-the-uk] => [always-friday-in-iceland]`

I admit, the first one is a bit funny, but are these legitimate tags that have been used on meta? I know some of the ones I've proposed, like `[friday-in-australia]` seem just as random, but that tag has been used, and I haven't seen these two.

Shouldn't we wait until we see at least one question mistagged before we institute tag synonyms?

Comment: you don't think it's just a *little* ridiculous that there are 10 synonyms for a tag that is essentially a joke itself? I actually thought someone was having a bit of fun with that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes -- we will be instituting a change so that you can only propose a synonym for an *existing* tag, added by a real live user, not imaginary tags that exist only in your head.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this was implemented, however I see moderators are still free to make up tags on the spot for the purpose of synonymizing

Comment: @Shog9 Excellent

Answer (score 10):

> Shouldn't we wait until we see at least one question mistagged before we institute tag synonyms?

No, and I'm frustrated by Jeff's recent decision to disallow "preventative synonyms" as I've called them before.

Why?

If we wait for a user to mistag a question, **we will never be able to find that question until someone combs through the new tags**. Yes, this will happen anyway (there's no getting away from it completely), but allowing entry of preventative synonyms (i.e., putting in plurals, hyphenated, British/American spellings, etc.) will cut down on these occurrences.

Yes, there should be a limit to these so that we're not wasting time putting in synonyms that will never be used, but at the same time, synonyms should focus on tags with more questions so all content is easily searchable.

For the existing proposals you've mentioned and any others you disagree with, downvote them. That's what the voting mechanism is there for.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't we wait until we see at least one question mistagged before we institute tag synonyms?

Sure, yes, we should wait; on meta it matters a lot less but managing the mammoth 600 synonyms on SO will be much harder if there are a ton that never apply. Fortunately we can sort by the number of times a synonym took effect and nuke old ones that never made a difference.

Comment: I think there are a lot more than 600 now, so the same logic applies, even more so