# Allow some "reverse" tag synonyms based on the ratio of the questions in the tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Based on my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59219/are-we-too-eager-with-tag-synonyms/59242#59242) (about allowing "preventative" tag synonyms) and a comment on my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63448/how-to-handle-reverse-synonyms/63454#63454), I'm proposing that a change be made to the algorithm that allows/denies tag synonym proposals.

---

The current system allows a proposal when

```
(# questions in target tag) >= (# questions in source tag)
```

---

The proposed new behaviour would allow a proposal when

```
(# questions in source tag) / (# questions in target tag) <= d
```

where `d` is decimal constant, probably somewhere in the range `2 <= d <= 3` (open to discussion, certainly).

---

What this means is that you still wouldn't be able to suggest a synonym that maps a 2,000-question tag to a 1-question tag, but you *would* be able to suggest a synonym that maps a 2,000-question tag to a 1,000-question tag.

This wouldn't open up the system completely, yet it would allow users more flexibility to put in the "right" synonym immediately (i.e., using a properly hyphenated version tag instead of the one with no hyphens; or using a plural version over singular). [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/function/synonyms) where I think the synonyms should be reversed that would be covered by this feature request.